# How to display object in template Flask as json?

Tags: python, flask

I have a route method:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET'])
def add_view():
    return render_template('add.html', categories=api.categories())
```

Then I tried to display `categories` as JSON inside template `add.html`:

```
{{ categories | json }}
```

It does not work

Comment: Please provide more details on what does not work, exactly. Error messages, wrong behaviour description, everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it hard to understand exactly what you're looking for here so I'd like to see more details but here's an answer based on what I **think** you're asking for (I'll edit this to suit your needs / remove this comment entirely if things change).

You're invoking `api.categories()` and are looking to render this as JSON on your HTML template, yes?

OK what I'd recommend here is to ensure that `api.categories()` is returning an instance of `dict`. For example, your `api.categories()` call should return something like this:

```
{
    "testKey1": "testValue1",
    "testKey2": "testValue2"
}
```

Now to render this as JSON in your HTML template. You can import the `json` module in your Flask module using the following import:

```
import json
```

Now your return statement in your `add_view` method will be as follows:

```
return render_template('add.html', categories=json.dumps(api.categories()))
```

You can now do something like as follows in your HTML template:

```
<script>
    document.write("{{categories}}");
<script>
```

This should render your JSON for you just fine.